# Extract lines from input text file to text file with some transformation with Mule 4

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I have a requirement where I need to read text file and extract some data and send the extracted to other system for which am unable to do it.

Input file:

```
1BoraBora Island                                                                                                                                                           
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
3BR          209078 BoraBora              6798989                                                                                                99999
1 BR  67854 JAIHIND  789                                                                                                 000Y247          9898983
2 BR  CR9   BoraBora 123                                                QK                                          J12Y64              00010520
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Output should be:

```
 
1BoraBora Island                                                                                                                                                          
0000000000000000000000
1 BR  67854 JAIHIND  789                                                                                                 000Y247          9898983
2 BR  CR9   BoraBora 123                                                QK                                          J12Y64              00010520
```

Need to extract only row having "BR" in it at 3th letter.
Please guide me how to achieve this in text format only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input is `text/plain'. Using a DataWeave script and the subscript() function you can extract a given position from the input:

```js
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output text/plain
var lines=payload splitBy "\n" // separate text into an array of lines
---
lines[0] ++"\n" ++ lines[1] ++"\n" 
++ (lines[2 to -1] // use the range selector to get the remaining lines
    filter (substring($,2,4)=="BR") // filter lines that have "BR" at the right position
    reduce ($$++"\n"++$) // concatenate the remaining lines again into a single text file
)
```

Output:

```json
1BoraBora Island                                                                                                                                                           
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1 BR  67854 JAIHIND  789                                                                                                 000Y247          9898983
2 BR  CR9   BoraBora 123                                                QK                                          J12Y64              00010520
```

Comment: Thank you @aled for your response but the response should be 



1 BR  67854 JAIHIND  789  000Y247          9898983                                                                                             
2 BR  CR9   BoraBora 123



if "BR" is present in 3rd letter of any row then it should get extracted the total line.
And this is jus a sample request the place of BR can be in any row.
Please guide me.

Comment: Please explain exactly the extraction rules from the input to obtain the output. As I see from the question the input has two lines, with a newline in between. What is exactly a row in this context?

Comment: I found that because the examples where not formatted as code samples the lines were lost. I fixed your format. I'll review the request again.

Comment: Updated the solution to match your request.

Comment: Extraction rules- Input file is a text file but it is  actually a flatfile so what happens when they extract and give it to us it becomes text file from that we need to extract only "BR" containing row which am considering as row.
If "BR is present in that it automatically extracts the row.

Comment: I am trying with %dw 2.0
output application/json
---

read(payload,"text/csv",{header:false}).*column_0 filter($ matches "^\d+ BR.+")
 it works only if the input payload is text and output is json then it is working but i need output as text file only hence I seeking for help

Comment: Please review my updated solution.

Comment: Thank you @aled
It works amazingly. i will keep in mind from next time how i should be differentiating it .

Comment: aled -I also need to add headers to my extracted list. I have updated the output in main question.
1BoraBora Island                                                                                                                                                          
0000000000000000000000
1 BR  67854 JAIHIND  789                                                                                                 000Y247          9898983
2 BR  CR9   BoraBora 123                                                QK                                          J12Y64              00010520

Comment: What's a header? How do you identify them?

Comment: we are assuming it as first two rows are header.

Comment: Just concatenate the first 2 two rows. I updated my answer to include the headers too. Feel free to upvote the answer if useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with Text, you can also use Regex with the [`scan`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-scan) function to scan all lines that matches your condition then [`joinBy`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-joinby) a new line character

```js
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
flatten(payload scan /(?<=^|\n).{2}BR.*/)
joinBy "\n"
```

`(?<=^|\n).{2}BR.*` Regex breakdown:

1. `(?<=` is a positive lookbehind, that means it will start matching the rest of the pattern only if it follows the pattern specified by it
2. `(?<=^|\n)` is positive lookahead with either start of string (`^`) of a new line (`\n`)
3. `.{2}BR.*` indicates any character twice followed by the literal BR then any number of any character thereafter

Comment: This is working amazingly. Thank you for your valuable response@harshankBansal